# How to make Nested Models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to django.
My task is to make a feature on shared documents in backend. Documents can have folders, like google docs.We will have list of documents within list of folders.

I created following model classes:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class File(models.Model):
    folder_name = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

So first, a folder will be created. Then a file will be uploaded in that folder.
My Questions are:

- In google docs, we can have folders inside folders. How can I update my model if I want to add this feature of adding folder inside folder and then storing file on it.
- What does FileField attribute actually do? I want to store the data in postgres database, not in my local storage. How to deal with that?
- What additional features should I add in my model for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

To add support for subfolders, I'd add a nullable foreign key from the `Folder` model to itself. Have a look at [the documentation for `ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in order to see how to reference itself.

To understand what a `FileField` actually does, I'd recommend reading [the documentation about File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Regarding file storage, I'm not sure storing the files in your database is a great idea. If you don't want to store files in the regular file system, Django has a quite flexible API for [custom storages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/files/storage/). You probably don't need to implement an alternative yourself. Most likely, someone else already made it and created a package you can use. E.g. [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which adds support for a range of popular cloud storages.

In general: I'd suggest you always turn to the Django docs when exploring new areas of Django. The documentation is, in my opinion, one of the key features of Django. So well written, it's always a joy going there :)